# Create Wrapper Class for Number in Julia

Tags: julia

I have several functions in Julia that all are doing isentropic relations given a certain temperature, pressure, or density ratio.  I would like to make three types that wrap Number (or Float64, whichever works) that represent the different types of ratios.

These types need to be distinguishable via type assertions (ie ::PressureRatio != ::TemperatureRatio).  I could make a single field composite type, but ideally it would subtype Number so that math operations work as expected.

Currently I have tried just making a generic subclass of Number, but then when I try to instantiate it, there is no convert method to go from Float64 to PressureRatio (for example).

Anyone have any ideas, or a better idea?

Thanks!

Comment: "Currently I have tried just making a generic subclass of Number, but then when I try to instantiate it, there is no convert method to go from Float64 to PressureRatio (for example)." Can you show what you tried? You're going to have to implement a bunch of methods. But it's not clear to me why you're doing this, unless you're trying to use the type system to perform unit calculations, in which case you should check out Unitful.jl

Comment: The idea was to avoid having a long (essentially) switch case of "am I using a pressure ratio, am I using a temp ratio, or am I using a density ratio?" via some extra string argument that is susceptible to user/developer error.

By creating types for these sorts of things, everything becomes much more explicit and Julia's multiple dispatch can be taken advantage of.

Comment: Also, it would kinda cool if this sort of use case was supported as a future language feature, it's pretty doable in OOP languages by just subclassing something with some dummy classes...but I could see how that would be somewhat complicated/annoying in certain cases.

Comment: This might be stating the obvious, but if you're following Jeff's answer, you don't need to extend methods for each of your new types. Just use the same field name in each of your new types, make them all a subtype of some abstract supertype, eg `MyAbstractFloat`, which in turn can be a subtype of `Number`, and then you only need to extend the standard methods to `MyAbstractFloat`. Does this make sense? (at least this is how I've done it in my codebase)

Comment: "Also, it would kinda cool if this sort of use case was supported as a future language feature, it's pretty doable in OOP languages by just subclassing something with some dummy classes". Yes, and Julia does it too through abstract types. The reason why this doesn't have an easy interface on the abstract types though is because the basic numbers in Julia are not composite types. They are bits types (or now primitives) which you can define by the number of bits, and then the basic methods are defined by LLVM calls.

Comment: So it wouldn't make sense to have dispatches in Base for `AbstractFloat` that say, call `+(x::AbstractFloat,y) = x.x+y` (i.e. `AbstractFloat` interface assumes it's a composite type with each time having a field `x` which is the internal number) since the Base types are not composite types and thus don't store the data as a field like that. But if you write your own small interface like this (Jeff shows which methods to overload), then every type which stores the number as `.x` will have all of the methods (as Colin mentioned).

Comment: I mean the idea would be to have a wrapper type that looks, acts, and quacks like a duck, but is distinguishable by something like mallard duck, Canadian duck, etc. I'm not sure how the Base types are defined precisely, but the idea would be that whatever you wrapped them with would not be composite (or composite if you were wrapping a composite), but I see your point on the abstract class with subtypes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of defining a new type of Number: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/14be0dcf3908d2767cb40266d26068c416aadbf1/examples/ModInts.jl

If you define methods similar to everything in that file, most basic things should work.